# How to use runtime options in 'rails new' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to use '-s' that is present in following runtime options.

> -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

I know how to use of --skip, but don't know the use of only '-s', is it a simplified way to use --skip??

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `--skip` is equivalent to `-s`, it is a common UNIX convention to provide a short and a long option to commands.

You just run

```
rails new my_awesome_app -s
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response.. But i want to know how to skip bundle using -s in rails 4..
rails new myapp --skip-bundle will be equivalent to which command using -s??

Comment: There isn't an equivalent with `-s` since it literally stands only for `--skip`. If you want to use `--skip-bundle` you can use `-B`. Check out `rails new -h` for all the options.